# How to remove the cap/plate/cover off this tap

Tags: taps, stuck

I've got a stuck cold water tap on the mixer tap below. If I could get the cover off the tap I'd be okay from that point I think but it's not budging.

I've sprayed plenty of WD40 into the sides of it but it doesn't pull, pop or turn at all.

Any ideas how I might get the cover off and get to the screw?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if a careful knife or razor blade might pop it off, the spring clamps could be pretty strong. If that fails to widen the gap, then it's a screw-on cap. You'll need to treat it like a faucet aerator that you don't want to scratch, by wrapping the cap with cloth, leather, rubber, plastic or even liberal tape & take big (long) pliers to it. It should be normal threads, loosen to the right.

Otherwise, I might try the shoulder sleeve below the stem...that looks removable. Not that I've seen it before, but the cap could be screwed from the inside as that stem looks quite thick.

Comment: I think the OP meant how is the cap fastened... but I think it is `screw on cap`. Try and unscrew the cap with "righty tight lefty untighty" - counter clockwise. Another way is to us a guitar pick and force it inbetween the seem to see if it will pop out (but usually is its a pop out one there is a small gap or edge to allow tiny screw driver to lift it)

Comment: Thank you, I don't know how I misread that. I updated my answer.